# Destroy a single list member

Tags: unity, 2d, unityscript

im trying to destroy a single game object using the following script but it destroys all of them , not the ones I want. I want to destroy the ones that the transform that holds this script collides with.

It's a 2D unity3d game btw.

The script :

```
var keys : List.<Transform>;

function OnTriggerEnter2D(coll : Collider2D)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        Destroy (keys[i].gameObject);
    }
}
```

I hope I was clear enough , don't hesitate to ask any questions.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by editing my code into this :

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(coll : Collider2D)
{
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Key")
        {
            Destroy (coll.gameObject);
            keysGathered ++;
        }
}
```

I didn't realise it was this simple.

Thank you for your time!